# WebClient Oauth2 - Token type must be Bearer error

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, webclient, spring-security-oauth2, spring-webclient

I'm implementing a `WebClient` with OAuth2 authorization in Java 11 and Spring Boot. The authorization service responds `200` with the token, but then it shows me the following error:
`"[invalid_token_response] An error occurred parsing the Access Token response: Token type must be Bearer"`

My WebClient Config:

```java
    @Bean
    public ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations(
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.apigee.token-uri}") String tokenUri,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.apigee.client-id}") String clientId,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.apigee.client-secret}") String clientSecret,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.apigee.scope}") String scope,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.apigee.authorization-grant-type}") String authorizationGrantType) {

        ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId(REGISTRATION_ID)
                .tokenUri(tokenUri)
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .scope(scope)
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST)
                .authorizationGrantType(new AuthorizationGrantType(authorizationGrantType))
                .build();

        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(registration);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations) {
        InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService = new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrations);
        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrations, clientService);
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(REGISTRATION_ID);
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth)
                .build();
    }
```

And the properties

```yaml
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.apigee.client-id=client-id
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.apigee.client-secret=client-secret
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.apigee.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.apigee.client-authentication-method=client_secret_post
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.apigee.scope=write,read
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.apigee.token-uri=https://host/v1/authorization
```

Answer (score 1):

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.apigee.token-uri=https://host/v1/authorization
```

This seems to be the problem here. The token-uri should be as follows:

```
https://hostname:port/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

For eg: If the IDP is Azure AD, the URI would be as follows:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Client URI>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```